# Issues with LowRankApprox in Julia

Tags: julia, matrix-factorization

I am trying to a Hermitian eigendecomposition using the pheigfact function provided with the LowRankApprox.jl package in Julia v0.6.0. Basically, it was just one line of code like:

```
(E, F) = pheigfact(A);
```

where A is a real symmetric positive definite matrix. However, I got the following error:

```
MethodError: no method matching
start(::LowRankApprox.PartialHermitianEigen{Float64,Float64})
Closest candidates are:
  start(!Matched::SimpleVector) at essential.jl:258
  start(!Matched::Base.MethodList) at reflection.jl:560
  start(!Matched::ExponentialBackOff) at error.jl:107
```

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR**

Use the function `pheig` not `pheigfact` to return a tuple of values and vectors

---

**Full answer**

I don't have the package but from the docs it looks like `pheigfact` returns a single element from which you can access the values/vectors using `getindex(x,ind::Symbol)`.

e.g.

```
F = pheigfact(A)
values=F[:values]
vectors=F[:vectors]
```

and if you try and assign a single element to a tube it will try and iterate over that a type that does not support it and so give you your error (i.e. the type does not have the method `start`). I could get a similar error doing either `x,y = :onetwo` or `start(:onetwo)`

**Solution**

Use the function `pheig` which does returns a tuple.

```
E, F = pheig(A)
```